# Google Play Store Subscriptions History

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, subscription

I'am using subscriptions in my application and it is working perfectly during testing. However, I didn't find a way to get user subscription history for all transactions.

Example:
-User subscribed to product id "sub1" for 3 months. (purchaseToken : "X")

-User canceled subscription for same product id "sub1"

-User resubscribed for same product id (purchaseToken : "Y")

In this scenario when querying queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() function it is returning only latest purchase. Also when using this [API][https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get] it returns only information of a specific purchase token ("Y" retreived from queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()).

Is there any other way to get user subscriptions history (Detailed transactions) 
?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching it turned out that there is no API that returns detailed transactions of specific subscription.